# Styled Components - Inline styling overlaps the media query styles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I am new to styled components. I am trying to change the flexDirection in media query but my inline styling `row` seems to overlap with media query styles.

Code Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-minsky-npubu

I want the `flexDirection` to change to `column` when width <600px and by default the direction should be `row`. **I cannot remove the row prop, that's the requirement**

I am not sure how to handle this issue. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: You can add `!important` keyword

Comment: @Shuvo Thanks for your help but is there a more proper way to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    flex-direction: column !important;
```

Comment: That's not the right approach, I guess.Or is it? What's the proper solution?

Comment: This is the only way to overwrite inline styles

Answer (score 1):

Modify your media query with following

```
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    color: red;
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
```